# Все библиотеки firebase должны быть выше или ниже версии 14.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-play-services, firebase-android

Делаю проект и пытаюсь подключить его к `firebase`, но он ругается и выдаёт: `All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0`, при этом всё соответствует его требованиям. Что не так? Graddle-файлы прикрепляю внизу:

app level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.max.mainwindow"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project level:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас `play-services-maps:11.0.4`. Тоже нужно поменять.

Подробнее про всё это дело можно в [блоге официальном](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html) почитать.